# Как сделать так, чтобы фон сужался только справа и слева?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Есть вот такая секция на сайте. Надо чтобы при изменении размера экрана/браузера(то есть при адаптиве), фон сужался только слева и справа, а центр фона оставался на своем месте. Да же не знаю как это реализовать. Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: .block {background-position:center 0px;}

Answer (score 1):

Просто используйте позиционирование фона по центру

```
background-position: center center;
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 100px;
}
section{
  position: relative;
  background: #279FA1;
  min-height: 200px;
}
section:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 100%; left: 50%;
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 15px 10px 15px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #279FA1 transparent;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<section></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body { 
    background-image: url('smiley.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
}
```